# Command that can work with and without tagging someone

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm looking for a way to have a command which will give different responses depending on whether you have tagged someone along with the command.

Here's what I got so far:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'attack',
    description: "uses attack embed",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {

var newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#A5775C')
        .setDescription(message.author.username + ' *attacked* '+ message.mentions.members.first().username);

var newEmbed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#A5775C')
        .setDescription(message.author.username + ' *attacked the enemy!*');

if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
       message.channel.send({embeds: [newEmbed]});
     }else{
       message.channel.send({embeds: [newEmbed1]});
     }
  }
}
```

When I try this format, the command where you ping someone works, but when you don't ping someone, nothing happens.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this code a try it requires less code and will check for a target.

```js
let target
if (message.mentions.members.first() === undefined) {
    target = 'the enemy.'
} else {
    target = message.mentions.members.first().username
}
const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#A5775C')
    .setDescription(`${message.author} attacked ${target}`)

message.channel.send({
    embeds: [newEmbed]
})
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it, but it doesn't seem to be working. Let me try something.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Ok, so the tagless command works, however, when we tag someone, the command doesn't work

Comment: I managed to get it to work. Apparently in
```
 target = message.mentions.members.first().user.username
```
the .user part isn't needed.

Thanks for the help!